# SQL Error [1821] [220008]: ORA-01821: date format not recognized

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to access `past-midnight time` from the timestamp and convert it to seconds and then add them together to get the whole value in seconds `AS seconds`.

I'm trying this-

```
SELECT 
    TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(a.date_column, 'hhhhh')) * 3600 +
    TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(a.date_column, 'mmmmm')) * 60 +
    TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(a.date_column, 'sssss')) AS seconds
FROM 
    DUAL
```

But I'm getting the error mentioned in the title.

Description-
`a.date_column` is in `varchar` format which was accessed through-

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(a.dte, 'YYYY/MM/DD') || ' ' || a.time, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS:FF3') AS date_column
```

and it looks like-

```
date_column
2018-04-02 04:24:22:000
2018-04-03 03:44:34:000
2018-04-04 02:19:45:000
2018-04-04 04:33:34:000
```

I'm expecting the total value in seconds. For example- 12876

Comment: Date formats are documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Format-Models.html). `hhhhh` and `mmmmm` aren't listed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXTRACT`:

```sql
SELECT date_column,
       EXTRACT(HOUR FROM date_column) * 3600
       + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM date_column) * 60
       + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM date_column) AS seconds
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (date_column) AS
SELECT TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:01.000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:01:00.000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 01:00:00.000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 23:59:59.999' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs the number of seconds post-midnight:

| DATE_COLUMN | SECONDS |
| --- | --- |
| 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 0 |
| 1970-01-01 00:00:01.000 | 1 |
| 1970-01-01 00:01:00.000 | 60 |
| 1970-01-01 01:00:00.000 | 3600 |
| 1970-01-01 23:59:59.999 | 86399.999 |

And for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (date_column) AS
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2018-04-02 04:24:22.000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2018-04-03 03:44:34.000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2018-04-04 02:19:45.000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2018-04-04 04:33:34.000' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs the number of seconds post-midnight:

| DATE_COLUMN | SECONDS |
| --- | --- |
| 2018-04-02 04:24:22.000 | 15862 |
| 2018-04-03 03:44:34.000 | 13474 |
| 2018-04-04 02:19:45.000 | 8385 |
| 2018-04-04 04:33:34.000 | 16414 |

If you want to total all those values then use `SUM`:

```
SELECT SUM(
         EXTRACT(HOUR FROM date_column) * 3600
         + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM date_column) * 60
         + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM date_column)
       ) AS seconds
FROM   table_name
```

Which outputs:

| SECONDS |
| --- |
| 54135 |

(And if you are going to get a total above one day and you want to restrict it to the post-midnight time for the total then use `MOD(total, 86400)`.)

---

If you want different methods then you can use `TO_CHAR` with the `HH24`, `MI` and `SS.FF` format models or with the `SSSSS.FF` format model (`FF` is not required if you are using `DATE` data types, which have a time component but no fractional seconds, rather than `TIMESTAMP`s, which also have a time component but may have fractional seconds).

For example:

```sql
SELECT date_column,
       EXTRACT(HOUR FROM date_column) * 3600
       + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM date_column) * 60
       + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM date_column) AS seconds,
       TO_CHAR(date_column, 'HH24') * 3600
       + TO_CHAR(date_column, 'MI') * 60
       + TO_CHAR(date_column, 'SS.FF') AS seconds2,
       TO_CHAR(date_column, 'SSSSS.FF') AS seconds3
FROM   table_name
```

Outputs:

| DATE_COLUMN | SECONDS | SECONDS2 | SECONDS3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-04-02 04:24:22.000 | 15862 | 15862 | 15862.000000000 |
| 2018-04-03 03:44:34.000 | 13474 | 13474 | 13474.000000000 |
| 2018-04-04 02:19:45.000 | 8385 | 8385 | 08385.000000000 |
| 2018-04-04 04:33:34.000 | 16414 | 16414 | 16414.000000000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WlAJ5-Lk)

Comment: I tried this solution already but what I want to calculate is- sum of Post Midnight (hours, minutes, and seconds).

Comment: @AnthonyGonzales This totals the post-midnight hours, minutes and seconds and returns the total in seconds. That appears to be exactly what the question asks for and exactly what you ask for, again, in the previous comment; so I am confused as to what the problem is.

Comment: I'm a little confused now with the query as I can't find any function or clause or anything alike to access the past-midnight hours.

Comment: @AnthonyGonzales `EXTRACT` will give you the number of hours/minutes/seconds since midnight. So would `TO_CHAR` with the format models `HH24`, `MI`, `SS.FF` or `SSSSS.FF` (but would return the values as strings, not numbers so there would be some casting required)

Comment: For example for accessing past-midnight seconds we generally use-
SELECT
TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP '2018-04-04 04:33:34.000', 'sssss')
FROM dual;

Comment: Does that mean that EXTRACT() automatically takes past-midnight values only?

Comment: @AnthonyGonzales `EXTRACT` and `TO_CHAR` both work with the component parts of the date. `EXTRACT(HOUR FROM date_column)` and `TO_CHAR(date_column, 'HH24')` will give exactly the same value, the number of hours since midnight. If you add the individual hour, minute and seconds components (either from `EXTRACT` or `TO_CHAR`) then you will get the same total as using the `TO_CHAR` with the `SSSSS` format model [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_8VriNWz). You are doing exactly the same thing with different  methods; pick whichever you want.